# Show alert() window in another tab?

Tags: javascript

*Edit: Browser notifications worked for me (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)*

Suppose that I have a browser tab that triggers an `alert()` window:

```
setTimeout( () => {
  alert("Message");
}, 5000);
```

Can I somehow make this alert message appear on top of another tab that I'm using?

Comment: If all tabs are attached because opened from the same source page ```const child = window.open()```, you can communicate using the instance and window.opener.

Comment: Is the content of the target tab from your own website, or do you mean you would like to have the pop up message shown to user on any other website she is currently on?

Comment: @TomiKokkonen The latter.

Comment: I can be wrong, but that sounds like a terrible idea for security and privacy if another page from an another domain could pop up an alert on current page. So I hope it's not possible :)

Comment: Maybe you could try browser notification and or actual pop ups as if user really wants this kind of behavior from your page she could then opt in.